# How to display composite field names in psql query results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

For queries made in `psql` which return composite-type columns, is it possible to have `psql` display both the field names *and* the field values of the composite types?

For example, given the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scientists (
    scientist_id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name   text,
    last_name    text
);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS achievements (
    scientist_id   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES scientists(scientist_id),
    description    text    NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO scientists (scientist_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES
    (1, 'Isaac', 'Newton'),
    (2, 'Marie', 'Curie')
;
INSERT INTO achievements (scientist_id, description) VALUES
    (1, 'Classical Mechanics'),
    (2, 'Research into Radioactivity')
;
```

the query

```sql
SELECT scientists, achievements FROM scientists
    LEFT JOIN achievements ON scientists.scientist_id = achievements.scientist_id;
```

will return

```
     scientists      |            achievements
---------------------+-------------------------------------
 (1,Isaac,Newton)    | (1,"Classical Mechanics")
 (2,Marie,Curie)     | (2,"Research into Radioactivity")
```

which lacks the field names of the composite types. Ideally there would be some configuration value I could set in psql which would enable displaying the field names for all queries.

I know that I could specify `SELECT (scientists).*, (achievements).*` to expand the query, but then I lose the advantage that composite types give - such as disambiguation between fields with the same names. Specifying `SELECT (scientists).*, (achievements).*` would give the column `scientist_id` twice, which is ok in this example, but confusing for more complex schemas where two unrelated fields might share the same name.

Comment: Well, `to_jsonb()` might produce something that *looks* more like you want it. But the question is how you plan to consume the data and why you don't just simply use the column names in the list after `SELECT` and do it the "old fashioned" but well known and proven way?

Comment: "*I lose the advantage that composite types give - such as disambiguation between fields with the same names.*" Could you explain that? I agree with sticky bit, if you want to see column names in your results query columns.

Comment: I've clarified the advantage of using composite types. Additionally, doing things the "old fashioned" way would mean possibly typing out 20+ column names for some of the queries I work with - not a preferable solution for ad-hoc queries (though it's ok for more common ones).

Comment: "would give the column `scientist_id` twice" -- Explicitly list the columns you want and possibly alias them.

Comment: That's all fine and good if you want to spend the time listing out a large number of columns, and know all the columns ahead of time. If you don't, then it's a tedious amount of time that could be spent on more productive things.

Comment: Well, that's the way to (properly) work with relations. If you want to operate on them you need to know their schemas (which *are* well defined and known at any time) and define the schemas of the results (partly to be also able to continue to work on them). That is *productive* work in that area. And after all you need to consume each column of the result in a certain way, so you need to somewhere address them individually anyway, if not in SQL somewhere in your consuming program...

Comment: In the end you have three options: you can either treat a column of a composite type as a single value, then you will have to live with that output. Or you properly normalize your model and ditch the composite types. Or you use the `.*` expansion. I disagree with your assumption that composite types are an advantage. I think in general de-normalizing a model has more disadvantage than advantages. If you have unrelated columns that have the same name, then you might want to re-think your naming conventions.

Comment: Well if you insist on maintaining your stance in comment "That's all fine and good if ..." then the answer to your question is **No**.